# C#: Problems while trying to transfer a Console Program into a GUI

Tags: c#

Im new to C#!
So my Problem: I got a C# Demo Program from an extern company, the program sets the settings of an extern device, than initialize it and starts recording the Data. The Data is written into the Console and streamed into a CSV at a Location i can choose. After pressing a Key in the Console the Recording stops. I am trying now to write a short GUI that starts and stops this Recording.
What I did:
I converted the main-method, which started the recoding, into a normal static method and deleted all writelines so the console doesnt start, than I created a Windows Form with 2 Buttons, one Start and One Stop. If I press Start, the Recording starts, but I cant do anything with the Gui it is like freeezed, a Console still appeares and i can only stop the process by pressing a key in the console.

Here is a snippit of the Console Code:

```
class BHJKL
{
    system
    private static A;


    private static B;


    // This method will be executed every time new data is received
    static void OnNewDataReceived(object sender, NewDataEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
         //some code in here


         using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\XYZ\File_Trial" + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear + ".csv", true))
         {
             //Writeline data..
         }

     }

}
```

// This was the Main Method before i changed it

```
    public static void Record()
    {



        // Here is some Code that configure the Settings of the device




        // initialize device
        // MORE CODE USING THE COMPANYS EXTERN LIBRARYS TO START THE DEVICE

        //start device
        deviceManager.DeviceStart();


        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) // as long as no key is pressed do...
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // do nothing, let the event processing thread that is managed by the library handle incomming data
        }

        //stop device
        deviceManager.DeviceStop();

        //unsubscribe event
        deviceManager.NewDataReceived -= OnNewDataReceived;

        //deinitialize device
        deviceManager.DeinitializeDevice();

        //dispose device
        deviceManager.Dispose();




    }
}
```

My Attempt:
Changing the main method into static Recording. 
Than by Pressing the Start Button, call the method.

Write this at the end of the method:

```
while (Rec==true) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); 
}
```

By Pressing the Stop Button: set.Rec(false)
But after Pressing the start Button, i cant press the stop button anyome.
I hope someone can understand my Problem and can give me some advices.

Comment: Trash what you did. Create a fresh GUI project, then include the relevant parts from the console example in a (more several) dedicated class to be used by your GUI.

Comment: Can you post the code handles Start?

Comment: I think you need a task with cancellation token that cancels the task when you press stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than sleeping in a loop, you should just let your `Start` method return. Move all of the code that comes after the sleep loop into your `Stop` button's click event handler.

(Depending on how the code is structured, you may also have to switch `deviceManager` from being a local variable to being a field in the class)

Answer (score 2):

Thread.Sleep blocks your UI from doing anything. Consider using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer